# Wortreihenfolge im Perfekt von Modalverben

Tags: word-order, modal-verb, perfect-tense

Ist es korrekt zu sagen

> Ich habe gewollt das zu lernen. (vielleicht ohne *zu*?)

Ich ahne, dass es seltsam klingt, auch wenn es korrekt ist. Aber ist es korrekt oder **muss man** sagen:

> Ich habe das lernen wollen.

Um den folgenden Satz zu übersetzen:

> I [wanted]/[have wanted] to learn this.

Comment: Nein, der erste Satz ist nicht korrekt. Folgendes wäre stattdessen aber möglich: Ich war gewillt, das zu lernen. Ich war willens, das zu lernen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nein, deine Konstruktion ist so nicht möglich. Englisch und Deutsch sind nicht nah genug miteinander verwandt, als dass man den Satzbau direkt übertragen könnte.

In deinem Fall hast du zwei Optionen:

- Wenn du unbedingt das Perfekt verwenden möchtest, **musst** du die infinitivische Form nehmen:

  > Ich habe das lernen wollen.
- Wenn es dir nur um die Vergangenheit an sich geht, kann man gut auf das Präteritum ausweichen:

  > Ich wollte das lernen.

Hintergrund: Das Perfekt verlangt eine Verbklammer. Alle anderen Bestandteile des Satzes müssen zwischen Hilfsverb (hier: *haben*) und Partizip (hier: *gewollt/wollen*) stehen. Du musst also den Infinitiv in diese Klammer ziehen. Das gilt sowohl für kurze (wie im Beispiel) als auch für lange Infinitive:

> Ich habe das, ohne mir der Folgen vollständig bewusst zu sein, gewollt.

Demnach wenn überhaupt *ich habe das lernen gewollt*, aber auch das klingt komisch, eben weil in diesen kurzen Fällen die Ersatzform *[…] wollen* zur Verfügung steht.